# Call a heavy PHP function through a loop AJAX or server-side

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, client-side-scripting, server-side-scripting

Which one is best when to choose from server-side or client-side?
I have a PHP function something like:

```
function insert(argument)
{
   //do some heavy MySQL work such as sp_call
   // that takes near about 1.5 seconds  

}
```

I have to call this function about 500 times.

```
for(i=1;i<=500;i++)
{
  insert(argument);
}
```

I have two options:

```
a) call through loop in PHP(server-side)-->server may timed out 
b) call through loop in JavaScript(AJAX)-->takes a long time.
```

Please suggest the the best one, if there is any third one.

Comment: Do you need the browser? If possible I would add the jobs to a job queue and run jobs in that queue periodically from a task scheduler like cron.

Comment: if you have no other option but to do it this way, always go with the thinnest server and fattest client you can. but you really should be trying to find a more elegant way of accomplishing the task... 1.5 seconds x 500 is about 12 minutes!!

Comment: This really sounds like a job for a queue/worker setup with no browser involved whatsoever.

Comment: What does your insert function do in general? Maybe there is a way to bring down the database calls from 500 to 2-3.

Comment: yes it takes along time in browser even more than 12 minutes becoz client-server distance.

Comment: no, @Ivan it is not possible. but the good thing  for me is that i have to call this once in a month

Comment: if i go with server side script,it will be fast enough but my server may fall out of memory e.g

Comment: Are you using a prepared statement with mysqli extension? That would dramatically reduce the time/memory requirements for a server side loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally I Got this.

a) Use AJAX if you wanna sure that it will complete. it is also user-friendly as he gets regular responses between AJAX calls.

b) Use Server Side Script if you almost sure that server will not get it down in between and want less load on client.

Now i am using Server Side Script with a waiting message window for the user and user waits for successful submission message else he have to try again.
with a probability that it will succeed in first attempt is 90-95%.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your server still needs to do all the work, so you can't use the clients computer to lessen the power needed on your server, so you have a choice of the following:

1. Let the client ask the server 500 times. This will easily let you show the process for the client, giving him the satisfactory knowledge that something is happening, or
2. Let the server do everything to skip the 500 extra round trip times, and extra overhead needed to process the 500 requests.

I would probably go with 1 if it't important that the client don't give up early, or 2 if it's important that the job is done all the way though, as the client might stop the requests after 300.

EDIT: With regard to your comment I would then suggest having a "start work"-button on the client that tells the server to start the job. Your server then tells a background service (which can be created in php) to do the work. And it can update it's process to a file or in a database or something. Then the client and the php server is free to timeout and log out without problems. And then you can update the page to see if the work is completed in the background, which can be collected from the database or file or whatever. Then you minimize both time and dependencies.

Comment: yes, you got it right almost. I am using the first one at present.Because i have doubt that server will out of memory or timed off if i go with the second one.

Comment: I am using exactly and exactly the same..but it takes double extra time.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any context for what you are trying to achieve - of key importance here are performance and whether a set of values should be treated as a single transaction.

The further the loop is from the physical storage (not just the DBMS) then the bigger the performance impact. For most web applications the biggest performance bottleneck is the network latency between the client and webserver - even if you are relatively close....say 50 milliseconds away...and have keeaplives working properly, then it will take a minimum of 25 seconds to carry out this operation for 500 data items.

For optimal performance you should be sending the data the DBMS in the least number of DML statements - you've mentioned MySQL which supports [multiple row inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and if you're using MySQLi you can also submit [multiple DML statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) in the same database call (although the latter just eliminates the chatter between PHP and DBMS while a single DML inserting multiple rows also reduces chatter between the DBMS and the storage). Depending on the data structure and optimiziation this should take in the region of 10s of milliseconds to insert hundreds of rows - both methods will be much, MUCH faster than having the loop running in the client even if the latency were 0.

The length of time the transaction in progress is going to determine the likelihood of the transaction failing - the faster method will therefore be thousands of times more reliable than the Ajax method.

As Krycke suggests, using the client to do some of the work will not save resource on your system - there is an additional overhead of the webserver, PHP instances and DBMS connection. Although these are relatively small, they add up quickly. If you test both approaches you will find that having the loop in PHP or in the database will result in significantly less effort and therefore greater capacity on your server.

Comment: Actually I wrote that he can't use the client as there will be no winning from it. So we are arguing the same point there.

Comment: Apologies Krycke - amending answer

Answer (score 0):

Once I had script which was running tens of minutes. My solutions was doing long request through AJAX with timeout 1 second and checking for result in another AJAX threads. Experience for user is better than waiting too long for response from php without ajax.

```js
$.ajax({
  ...
  timeout: 1000
})
```